# Why does a string is considered as color in HTML?

Tags: html

Okay, this might seem like my computer's fault, but I tested this with different devices, I get the same result on every device.
While setting the background color of a html to **blue**, I did a typo and wrote **bluee** and I got violet color. I don't know why it's happening.

```html
<body bgcolor="bluee"><div style=color:red;>
Weird Color
</div></body>
```

Comment: "bluee" is converted by the browser as hex color format "#b00ee0".
There is no "l" and "u" letters for hex color, so the browser is replacing the wrong letters with "0". The hex color format has 6 letters/numbers so the browser is completing the missing/wrong letters with "0". Hope that this answers your question :)